# Using another function as a method in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Writing in pure javascript, how can i attach a function i created as a method to a dom selector?

```
var button = document.getElementById('dropdown-trigger'),
    dropdownList = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-list');


button.addEventListener('mouseover', displayDropdown);

function toggleClass(className) {
  //toggle function here
}

function displayDropdown() {
  // I want to do something like: 
  dropdownList.toggleClass('none')
};
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not use use jQuery?

Comment: `hasClass` is unused. Did you mean `toggleClass`?

Comment: @JeffreyA.Gochin this has nothing to do with jQuery....

Comment: @DanPantry but jQuery would make this trivial

Comment: jQuery would make *adding and removing classes* trivial. It would not make adding methods to the DOM any more (or less) trivial.

Comment: @DanPantry jQuery also makes it easy to work on whole collections, especially results of selectors.

Comment: I would go with jQuery as well. See [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: @JeffreyA.Gochin Currently jsut trying to write in pure JS. Ive been using Jquery for so long that i want to touch up on pure javascript

Comment: I don't really understand the viewpoint. OP is asking how to extend the DOM, *not* how to work on whole collections (which is trivial in Es5). As for not extending the DOM, [web components](http://webcomponents.org/), a new tech, uses exactly that (albeit in a more isolated instance. There is no need to add an extra library to achieve what OP wants to achieve just because he wants to iterate over a selector.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly. I meant to put toggleClass and not hasClass

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio I do not see how extending the DOM is a bad idea makes this a valid jQuery usage. OP's question is *specifically* about extending the DOM. Telling him to 'just use jQuery' doesn't change the subject matter.

Comment: @RichardBustos I get that.  Maybe play with ES6 then. Have not tried it myself yet, but from what I have read it makes JavaScript much more object oriented.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*created as a method*", but I think you're looking for `toggleClass.call(this, 'none')`

Comment: This is becoming a lengthy discussion, you might want to move this to chat room.

Comment: @Bergi I want to do something like button.toggleClass()..

Comment: @RichardBustos: [No you don't](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Otherwise, use prototype.js.